# Slack integration in fastlane is giving Exception: the server responded with status 400

Tags: slack-api, cicd, fastlane

I have a Slack lane to send a message when my app is released to Firebase

```
desc "Sent slack message"
  lane :slackMsg do
    slack(
      slack_url: "https://hookforslack.com/asdnasd/abcd",
      payload: {
        "releaseNotes": "testing slack message",
        "url": "https://www.google.com",
        "version": "3.7.2.3"
      }
    )
  end
```

But I am always getting an Exception: the server responded with status 400. I tried to post a request to the hook URL with Postman and it was successful. So it should not be an issue of the hook

This works

```
curl --location 'https://hookforslack.com/asdnasd/abcd' \
--header 'Content-Type: text/plain' \
--data '{
    "version":"test",
    "url":"test",
    "releaseNotes":"test"
}'
```

and I am getting the message in the channel. Any idea how I can debug this? Or is it a bug?